# Cucumber before hook runs after Given step?

Tags: cucumber

When I run something in the Before hook it seems to happen after the first Given step.

```
Scenario: Stack Overflow Example
  Given some condition
  When something happens 
  Then something should be

Before do
  puts 'hello'
end
```

Outputs:

```
Scenario: Stack Overflow Example
  Given some condition
    Hello
    ....
```

This happens for each step.

Is this a misunderstanding on my part or a cucumber feature? How do I run something before the given step?

Many thanks in advance.

R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the technical reason but cucumber wont print using a plain 'puts' statement until after the scenario is finished.

Try STDOUT.puts "hello" and you will see that the Before hook runs first.

Comment: Or you can output timestamp to see when things are happening: timestemp = Time.new and then puts timestemp.strftime("%H:%M:%S.%L").